# How to add new column from another dataframe based on values in column of first dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

Guys I have 2 dataframes **df** and **population**.
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMVZb.jpg)

[population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt7Uj.jpg)

I simply want to add new column named **Population** to **df** and to add population numbers from  dataframe **population** to this column. I want to have population data next to each city.

How can I manage this ? Any advices?

**Ideal Solution**

```
Product Province    Quantity  Population
PRODUCT_A   ankara  16          5663322
PRODUCT_A   ankara  25          5663322
PRODUCT_A   ankara  56          5663322
PRODUCT_A   ankara  16          5663322
PRODUCT_A   adana   11          2258718
PRODUCT_A   adana   25          2258718
PRODUCT_A   ankara  35          5663322
PRODUCT_A   adana   54          2258718
PRODUCT_A   adana   17          2258718
PRODUCT_A   adana   30          2258718
PRODUCT_A   adana   12          2258718
PRODUCT_A   ankara  18          5663322
PRODUCT_A   ankara  14          5663322
PRODUCT_A   ankara  21          5663322
PRODUCT_A   aydin   16          1119084
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done via a `join` operation which in pandas can be done with `.merge()`.

Kindly try using the following:

```
df = df.merge(population,how='left',on='Province')
```

Also please consider reading the following answer for a [detailed guide on joins and merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: In the future, please consider carefully whether it is actually necessary to post an answer when we have a canonical Q&A covering the subject already. It is probably better to just vote to close the question as a duplicate. This really helps in keeping the site clean and reducing the duplication of information. Thanks!